# Mod_rewrite rule for one URL with percent

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I don't get it. I have a htacces-file for single URLs to be redirected.

example:

```
Redirect 301 /upload/pdfs/2014/12345678.pdf /upload/documents/12345678.pdf
```

Ok, works so far.

But now I have to redirect this URL:

/com/cars/detail/1234/[DB%0A%0Alink].html

to:

http://www.domain.de/Car-JohnDoe

I've tried a lot of expressions like:

```
Redirect 301 /com/cars/detail/1234/[DB%0A%0Alink].html http://www.domain.de/Car-JohnDoe
Redirect 301 /com/cars/detail/1234/([^0-9]*) http://www.domain.de/Car-JohnDoe
Redirect 301 /com/cars/detail/1234/([^0-9]*)$ http://www.domain.de/Car-JohnDoe
Redirect 301 /com/cars/detail/1234/(.*)$ http://www.domain.de/Car-JohnDoe
Redirect 301 /com/cars/detail/1234/(.*)$ http://www.domain.de/Car-JohnDoe
RedirectMatch 301 ^/com/cars/detail/1234/(.*)$ http://www.domain.de/Car-JohnDoe
Redirect 301 /com/cars/detail/1234/[DB\%0A\%0Alink].html http://www.domain.de/Car-JohnDoe
```

But nothing worked at all.
The "1234" is an ID, so everything that comes afer  that coul be a wildcard/placegolder. But actually I need a rule only for this single URL.

I hope you understand what I mean (sorry for my bad english)...

Best wishes
Bazi

Answer (score 0):

This should work to match `/com/cars/detail/1234/[DB%0A%0Alink].html` and redirect to `/Car-JohnDoe`:

```
RedirectMatch 301 "^/com/cars/detail/1234/\[DB\s+link\].html" /Car-JohnDoe
```

For other rules also make sure to use `RedirectMatch` instead of `Redirect`